# Highest value number in a loop multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an INSERT loop and I need to add a reference number to it. I need all of the reference numbers in the loop to be the same. I know that with MAX() I can select the highest number in the table. But if I loop it will just increase with each loop while I need it to stay the same.

Is there a way of doing this in the query itself? Or is the only way to save it in a variable outside of the loop?

Example code:

```
    for($i=2;$i<=$row_count;$i++){ // Loops 3 times (example)
    $part = $vehicle.'_part'.$i;
    $description = $vehicle.'_description'.$i;
    $imageName = $vehicle.'_image'.$i;
    $parts[] = array(
        'part' => $_SESSION[$part],
        'image' => $_SESSION[$part],
        'description' => $_SESSION[$description]);
    }

    foreach($parts as $onePart){    
            $queries[] = "INSERT INTO searches_tbl (ref_nr, vozila_id, korisnici_id, part, description, image)
                        VALUES (???, (SELECT id FROM vozila_tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), 
                            (SELECT id FROM korisnici_tbl WHERE email = '".$email_address."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), '".$onePart['part']."', '".$onePart['description']."', '".$onePart['image']."')";
    }
```

Comment: is this reference number you want to add arbitrary? Why not just do INSERt... (reference_column, ...other columns) VALUES (123, (SELECt... )) ?

Comment: It needs to increase by one each time. But not inside the loop. So if it loops 3 times and the highest number in the table is for example 100, it needs to be 101 all 3 times.

Comment: So retrieve the max outside the loop. That'll give you concurrency problems though. The only way to do this right is to make all of this into one query, wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Is there a way to do the loop in one query then?

Comment: keep the max value in session.

Comment: Unless you identify the set of parts by a single identifier, there's no way for the query to determine whether an incoming INSERT should use the current maximum ref_nbr (i.e. 101 3 times), or jump up to the next ref_nbr.

Comment: Does vozila_id represent a collection of parts for a search?

Comment: vozila_id is the id of the vehicle. I can't use that or korisnici_id for it unfortunately. I guess Ill make another select query then outside the loop and save the MAX()+1 in a variable and use it in the loop although I wanted to avoid making another query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new table, ie `searches_ref` with just an AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key-column.

> CREATE TABLE `searches_ref` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY
>   KEY );

You would then insert a new line in `searches_ref` before the loop, and get a new id you can use in the loop.

This way, you should not have concurrency issues (which you will probably get using `MAX()`)